# How much did he spend the last $5$ day $?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A man has a habit of spending an amount equal to the date on that day . For example Rs.$18$  on the $18$ th of the month and so on.
>
> Now on a fine day he is asked how much he had spent the last $5$ days, he answers $63$ . What were the dates $?$

Consider the dates to be $d,d+1,d+2,d+3,d+4$. Then $$5d+10=63\\or,\ \ 5d=53.$$

Or may be the dates are $d-2,d-1,d,d+1,d+2$ which gives $$5d=63$$

and both these methods are wrong . As dates are not consecutive natural numbers ranging all  over $\mathbb N$.So , I assumed there have been two different months involved and with a few trials found the dates to be $28,29,1,2,3$ in a leap year from February to March .

It was puzzle math . So may be this  trial was the only way to find the result . Please tell me if otherwise .

Comment: You solved the problem correctly. Clearly, that's the only solution because $29+30+1+2+3=65$ and $30+31+1+2+3=67$, so no month ending in $30$ or $31$ can yield a sum of $63$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is right but the case is that maybe he is asked on Monday of first week of next month where $date$ is $1$ for eg $28,29,1,2,3$ as it cant be $30,31$ month reason given by Noble Mushtak so consider february of $2016$ as it is leap year it has $29$ days so this is the only solution

Comment: What IS a "mushtak" and how does it get to be noble?

Comment: see the comments it is username

Answer (score 0):

Once you have figured out that you have to span a month break, you can reason that there must be two days at the end of the old month because they will contribute about $30$ each.  Three days would be around $90$, too big and one would be around $30$, too small.  That says the three days of the new month contribute $1+2+3=6$, so the old month must contribute $57$, which is $28+29$.